# Stopwatch and DateTime.UtcNow producing unexpectedly large timing variations

Tags: c#, datetime, timing, stopwatch

We have application logs that record performance information for various expensive operations. We use both `Stopwatch` and `DateTime.UtcNow` in our logging, and we are finding that these values can differ MUCH more than would be expected, **even given DateTime.UtcNow's ~20ms precision**. My question is **what could cause this and can it be fixed?**

The information recorded is:

- StartTime (`DateTime.UtcNow`)
- Duration (`TimeSpan.FromSeconds((after - before) / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency)`, where `after` and `before` are the values of `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` at the beginning and end of the operation
- EndTime (`DateTime.UtcNow`)

**You would expect EndTime to be close to StartTime + Duration, but in some cases it is way off**. We sampled 10000 such measurements, looking for cases where EndTime and (StartTime + Duration) differed by more than 20ms. We found the following:

- ~2% of entries are off by > 20ms
- Of these, they are off by an average of 100ms (max is 1.4seconds)
- Of these, in some cases the stopwatch-calculated end time is greater than the DateTime-based end time, but in most cases the stopwatch time is smaller

**Machine info**

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V VM running on top of Windows Server 2012 R2
- 32GB ram for VM, 8 virtual CPUs

Comment: Here's part of an [article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two) by Eric Lippert about why stopwatch is better than calls to `DateTime.Now` for measuring how much time has passed in a program.

Comment: @Chase Can I ask you the length of the operations measured? Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, seem as though utcnow has an approximate resolution of about 10 milliseconds so that could explain some of the difference you are observing.

Comment: These are based off of actual system measurements running over a long period of time? Are the deviations at all correlated with the length of the operations? One theory could be that the system clock was being automatically adjusted which affects `DateTime.UtcNow` but not `Stopwatch` measurements. VMs are normally syncing to the host fairly often.

Answer (score 7):

This is to be expected.   `StopWatch` uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` (QPC) under the hood, while `DateTime.UtcNow` uses the computer's real-time clock (RTC).

- QPC comes from your CPU's timestamp counter (TSC), and is highly *precise*, but has no basis for *accuracy* with relation to UTC.
- The RTC is on the computer's motherboard, and is usually built with cheap crystal oscillators.  It is *accurate*, but not *precise*.

For measuring elapsed time, you want precision, and thus should use `Stopwatch`.

For getting the current time of day, you want accuracy, and thus should use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

A great read with lots of supporting details [can be found here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx).

The variations you've measured are due to clock drift in the RTC.  Your RTC will (all by itself) fall a few milliseconds ahead or behind of real time.  This is quite common, and is periodically corrected by NTP synchronization.  For minor adjustments, the OS will spread out the correction in smaller intervals, a few milliseconds at a time, over the course of several seconds.

As far as a workaround goes, you could consider a class like this:

```
public static class PreciseClock
{
    private static readonly DateTime StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    private static readonly Stopwatch Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    public static DateTime GetCurrentUtcTime()
    {
        return StartTime + Stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

However, the downside is that you are making the assumption that the RTC is in perfect sync when the class is initialized.  In reality, you have no guarantee of that.

If you wanted *some* level of guarantee, you might consider making the NTP call *yourself*.  I've implemented a class that does exactly that in [NodaTime.NetworkClock](https://github.com/mj1856/NodaTime.NetworkClock).  It implements the `IClock` interface from [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org). It periodically makes a call to an NTP server, and tracks the time between calls using a `Stopwatch`.  You would use it like this:

```
// grab the clock's singleton instance
var clock = NetworkClock.Instance;

// optionally set the ntp server during your app's startup
clock.NtpServer = "pool.ntp.org"; // or whatever server you want to sync with

// Get the current utc time whenever you like
DateTime utcNow = clock.Now.ToDateTimeUtc();
```

Also, there is such a thing as a "Multimedia Timer", or "High Precision Event Timer" (HPET) that is available on most modern hardware.  It offers *even greater precision* than QPC.  However, there is no direct class that exposes that in .NET Framework.  If you search you will find a few implementations that wrap the Win32 functions that provide it.  Usually, this is overkill unless you're doing real-timey things like graphics or audio.

Comment: I can buy that these would be off by a few ms, but I am seeing hundreds of ms off. Would what you're describing really account for that much difference?

Comment: Sure, it could easily be that or even larger.  It all depends on the quality of the RTC crystal on the motherboard.  Some hardware is better than others.  On my box, I've measured 10 to 60 ms corrections, but there's no reason they couldn't be larger on other hardware.  Also, you said you were running this on a virtual machine, and its entirely possible that is impacting the results.  I'm not entirely sure of the mechanics of RTC virtualization, but I'm pretty sure the host OS would have to relay the RTC value to the guest, and there could be latency there.

Comment: You might consider running the same tests directly on the server hardware and see if it makes a difference.